# c# Action<T> How to handle with anonymous methods

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, action, anonymous-methods

I've recently explored c# to myself. But stuck with this problem.

So I have a method dbExec

```
public void dbExec(Action<OleDbCommand> func)
{
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        func(cmd); 
    }
}
```

delegate,

```
public delegate void DelCmd(OleDbCommand cmd);
```

and another method:

```
public ICollection<string> CheckUserPermissions() 
{
    List<string> logins = new List<string>();
    DelCmd delCmd = delegate(OleDbCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PERMISSIONS.LOGIN FROM PERMISSIONS";
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) while (rdr.Read()) logins.Add(rdr["LOGIN"].ToString());  
    };
    dbExec(delcmd);
    return logins;
}
```

The problem with `dbExec(delcmd);` statement. The error is "delcmd doesn't exist in current context". How to pass an anonymous method as a parameter to another method with Action declared parameter?

Comment: That's because upper-case `C` matters :) `delcmd` should be `delCmd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also avoid defining a delegate altogether.

Like this:

```
public ICollection<string> CheckUserPermissions()
{
    List<string> logins = new List<string>();

    Action<OleDbCommand> delCmd = cmd => 
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PERMISSIONS.LOGIN FROM PERMISSIONS";
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            while (rdr.Read()) logins.Add(rdr["LOGIN"].ToString());
    };
    dbExec(delCmd);
    return logins;
}
```

Edit: I actually mean what Servy wrote in the comment on the other answer, but he described it way better.

Comment: That will be a Lambda Expression.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo - it should be `delCmd` instead of `delcmd`. C# is a case-sensitive language

UPDATE: `DelCmd` is not same as `Action<OleDbCommand>` - that is different types, and you even can't cast delegates to each other. But you can create new action delegate:

```
dbExec(new Action<OleDbCommand>(delCmd));
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was actually delCmd. And error is "most overloaded method for ...dbExec(System.Action<System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand" has few incorrect arguments.

Comment: Rather than converting one delegate to the other just remove the custom delegate definition and assign the anonymous delegate to an `Action` right from the start.